# How to use binding in both a fragment and within its included layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-databinding

Say I have a fragment defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="cpaTabViewModel"
            type="org.romco.example.CpaTabViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pac_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{cpaTabViewModel.testString}"
            tools:text="test" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/addPerformedPAField"
            layout="@layout/add_performed_pa"
            app:cpaTabViewModel="@{cpaTabViewModel}"/>

[...]

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The included layout is add_performed_pa.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="cpaTabViewModel"
            type="org.romco.example.CpaTabViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        tools:showIn="@layout/cpa_tab_fragment">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/inputActivitySpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancelButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cancelButton"
            app:entries="@{cpaTabViewModel.activities}" <---- THIS CAUSES THE PROBLEM
            tools:listitem="@layout/sample_textview" />


[...]

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

The class representing the fragment is CpaTabFragment.kt:

```
class CpaTabFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var cpaTabFragBinding: CpaTabFragmentBinding

    private val cpaTabViewModel: CpaTabViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, CpaTabViewModel.Factory(activity?.application!!))
            .get(CpaTabViewModel::class.java)
            .apply {
                setPeriodType(arguments?.getSerializable(ARG_SECTION_TYPE) as PlanPeriodType)
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        cpaTabFragBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.cpa_tab_fragment, container, false)

        cpaTabFragBinding.testTextView.text = "TEST HEADER"

        cpaTabFragBinding.addPerformedPAField.root.visibility = View.GONE

        cpaTabFragBinding.cpaTabViewModel = cpaTabViewModel


// (this next line is replaced by passing the viewModel in the <include app:cpaTabViewModel="@{cpaTabViewModel} - I hope this is correct, but that's beside the point here)"
//        cpaTabFragBinding.addPerformedPAField.cpaTabViewModel = cpaTabViewModel



        return cpaTabFragBinding.root
    }
```

Obviously, I removed most of the unimportant (or at least what I'm hoping is unimportant) code above, leaving only what I think is relevant here.

Without actually using data-binding in the add_performed_pa.xml layout (the line marked with "THIS CAUSES THE PROBLEM"), the entire thing works fine. I can access the included layout as a binding just fine, change it's root visibility, even access any elements in it, etc.

However, as soon as I try to add any data-binding into the included .xml, app won't compile, and the error is the following:

```
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\org\romco\example\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import org.romco.example.databinding.AddPerformedPaBindingImpl;
```

I can't really find anyone else with this problem. Can you please help?

Comment: did you tried with clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I tried rebuilding (and clean+rebuilding) multiple times, still the same error.

Comment: invalidate caches and gradle clean and rebuild?

Comment: Unfortunately, still the exact same error when I build it :( . I'll try to play around with inflating the included layout or something, worst case I could just make it into another fragment, but at that point I'd have a fragment within a fragment within a fragment and that doesn't sound very clean...

Comment: After changing some ids back and forth and adding some calls to the bindings, it now compiles (even after reverting almost everything back to the state in which it was when I posted this question). I'll try to figure out if I actually did something, or if it was just a strange temporary issue I had on my system, then post an answer.